# Flush/clear a socket reader or rebuild line?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new to working with `Socket` and have perhaps painted myself into a corner with a spurious design. I *think* I'd like to find a way to purge or flush the contents of a line decorating a Socket's `InputStream`. But maybe I've set things up incorrectly?

The `Socket` is tasked with repeatedly running the following cycle, on demand, on a background thread. A `Runnable` is instantiated that does the following tasks, then completes:

1. Send a message to server
2. Listen for an "ACK"
3. Wait for response from server
4. Read and "log" response
5. Send "ACK"

The runnable holds a class variable that is responsible for reading messages from the `ServerSocket`. `inLine` is instantiated in a separate method which is used to establish the connection.

```
inLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

My issue is that I am trying to figure out how to handle a test case scenario where the `SocketServer` sends an "extraneous" message during the interval when the client is dormant. On the next iteration of the cycle, this "extra" message is in the cue ahead of the expected "ACK" in step 2.

I was thinking I would remove any pending messages from the `inLine` variable prior to launching the runnable. But I don't see any means to do this. There are no *flush* or *clear* methods on `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader`. Nor are there any methods that I can find which allow one to inspect if there are any messages in the queue, along the lines of an iterator's `hasNext()` method.

Is there something I am missing?

Should I just declare and instantiate the `inLine` anew with each cycle? I was hesitating to do this because I don't know how expensive it is to continually repeat this operation. (As I said, I'm new to working with Socket-based communications.)

Would something like the following at the top of the cycle be considered ugly, or reasonable?

```
// clear out any messages sent during dormant time
socket.setSoTimeout(10); // arbitrary, very short timeout
while (true) {
    try {
        in.readLine();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {   
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: There are wonderful folks at StackOverflow who I know are doing their best to keep questions in conformance with site standards. If you have a suggestion to help me improve the question, it would be appreciated. Should a question like this perhaps be better posted at "Code Review" now that I have added a plausible routine for clearing the input line?

Comment: Why the ACKs? TCP already does that itself. If your messages don't arrive you will find out via exceptions or timeouts. Adding your own ACKs is just complicating your life for no benefit. 10ms is far too short for a read timeout, and a `readLine()` call that doesn't store and test the result is pointlessly throwing away data.

Comment: I understand that there is a degree of redundancy with the "ACK". The person requesting the code wanted each message to include an acknowledgement. You are probably right that it would be valid to remove these operations. As for the "pointlessly throwing away data", the reason is that IF there is data at this stage, it is pointless/erroneous and needs to be discarded.

Comment: Well it is poor design, as is a server that sends an unsolicited message that you can do nothing with but discard. I suggest a design review.